# Create react native library and add CocoaPods to that library

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods

My Simple question is that how to add CocoaPods to React Native Library created by us. The method of creating React Native library is in this link https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-setup. I have read this https://shift.infinite.red/beginner-s-guide-to-using-cocoapods-with-react-native-46cb4d372995 to add CocoaPod to React Native Project.
But if follow the these steps for React Native Library i have the following error after running.

> **error**: Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it
>   exited with error code 65. To debug build logs further, consider
>   building your app with Xcode.app, by opening HelperProject.xcworkspace

Is there another method to add CocoaPod to React Native library?

Comment: I am in the process of creating a react native library that depends on the native SDKs. I can't make the react-native link to automatically install my s.dependency in the podspec file. did you manage to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution

first delete **ios/build** folder then run

```
sudo react-native run-ios
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me. but, why is the root required?

Answer (score 0):

If you get error like the image, Only run your command with `sudo` at the beginning. 
Like: 
`sudo react-native run-ios` then enter your password.

[image]